# 404 error with Postman while trying to test springboot code

Tags: spring-boot

I was following a tutorial to save and retrieve images from database using spring boot and angular.
I was trying to test it with Postman, putting an image in the db but getting the 404 error.
Below is the picture of postman
Can anyone explain to me what it is due to? thank you all

ImageModel.java

```js
package com.javainuse.model;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "image_table")
public class ImageModel {
    public ImageModel() {
        super();
    }
    public ImageModel(String name, String type, byte[] picByte) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.picByte = picByte;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    //image bytes can have large lengths so we specify a value
    //which is more than the default length for picByte column
    @Column(name = "picByte", length = 1000)
    private byte[] picByte;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public byte[] getPicByte() {
        return picByte;
    }
    public void setPicByte(byte[] picByte) {
        this.picByte = picByte;
    }
}
```

ImageRepository.java

```js
package com.javainuse.db;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.javainuse.model.ImageModel;
public interface ImageRepository extends JpaRepository<ImageModel, Long> {
    Optional<ImageModel> findByName(String name);
}
```

ImageUploadController

```js
package com.javainuse.controller;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import com.javainuse.db.ImageRepository;
import com.javainuse.model.ImageModel;
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(path = "image")
public class ImageUploadController {
    @Autowired
    ImageRepository imageRepository;
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public BodyBuilder uplaodImage(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Original Image Byte Size - " + file.getBytes().length);
        ImageModel img = new ImageModel(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getContentType(),
                compressBytes(file.getBytes()));
        imageRepository.save(img);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @GetMapping(path = { "/get/{imageName}" })
    public ImageModel getImage(@PathVariable("imageName") String imageName) throws IOException {
        final Optional<ImageModel> retrievedImage = imageRepository.findByName(imageName);
        ImageModel img = new ImageModel(retrievedImage.get().getName(), retrievedImage.get().getType(),
                decompressBytes(retrievedImage.get().getPicByte()));
        return img;
    }
    // compress the image bytes before storing it in the database
    public static byte[] compressBytes(byte[] data) {
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(data);
        deflater.finish();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!deflater.finished()) {
            int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Compressed Image Byte Size - " + outputStream.toByteArray().length);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
    // uncompress the image bytes before returning it to the angular application
    public static byte[] decompressBytes(byte[] data) {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while (!inflater.finished()) {
                int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (DataFormatException e) {
        }
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Postman error
[postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTWVL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi elfuso please add path slash example

```
  @RequestMapping(path = "/image")
```